# Output an object with color and backgroundColor in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have an object named `$myObject` like:

```
@{attr1=My first attribut;attr2=My second attribut;....}
```

The object is displayed properly when I use only the object name:

```
PS > $myObject
attr1 : My first attribut
attr2 : My second attribut
```

I would like to display my object with a specific color. I tried to reproduce [the example #4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-7#:%7E:text=The%20Write%2DHost%20cmdlet%20customizes,use%20to%20separate%20displayed%20objects.) with write-host.

The background and the foreground color works but my object is displayed like "an object":

```
@{attr1=My first attribut;attr2=My second attribut;....}
```

I tried multiple combination like that:

```
$myObject | write-host -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
write-output $myObject -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
write-output $myObject | write-host -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
write-host  $myObject -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
```

No one works.

Any idea how to do that? thanks!

Comment: `Write-Host ($myObject |Out-String) -ForegroundColor DarkGreen`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Write-Host` takes an input object, converts that to a *string* and writes it to the host application's screen buffer - so if you don't want it to print the default string representation of your object (ie. `@{prop=value;...}`), we'll have to convert it to a preferred format *before* passing it to `Write-Host`.

To get a string reflecting the default formatting PowerShell would have otherwise applied to the object, use `Out-String`:

```bsh
Write-Host ($myObject |Out-String) -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
```